# Как выбрать несколько данных из строк с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть Вот такие строки

```html
<a class="category__heading__name" href="/category/DVHrj/categ-name">Categ Name</a><span class="category__heading__thin">(201 items)</span><span class="category__heading__thin">(6P)</span>
    <a class="category__heading__name" href="/category/DVHrj/categ-name">Categ Name</a><span class="category__heading__thin">(201 items)</span><span class="category__heading__thin">(6P)</span>
    <a class="category__heading__name" href="/category/DVHrj/categ-name">Categ Name</a><span class="category__heading__thin">(201 items)</span><span class="category__heading__thin">(6P)</span>
```

Каким регулярным выражением нужно воспользоваться, чтобы вытащить такие данные:
What regular expression should i use to get:

1. DVHrj - Код между /category/ и символом / который идет следом за кодом
2. Categ Name - Содержимое тега "а"
3. 6 - Содержимое между "(" и "P)"

Comment: А в чём у вас сложность, если нужно именно с регулярками?

Comment: Я в них совсем не разбираюсь. Я смог получить только код, а дальше не смог

Comment: А вы как с страницей работаете? В браузере, в Node.js с cheerio или puppetteer? Просто парсить HTML регулярками обычно не советуют, проще это делать через DOM. Поэтому хорошо бы узнать про контекст вашей проблемы, вдруг можно сделать более надёжным способом.

Comment: В браузере, в консоли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку вы работаете в браузере, основной парсинг стоит сгрузить на штатный парсер HTML и использовать максимально DOM API — получить сначала чистые значения атрибутов или текстового содержимого нужных элементов, а потом уже эти строки доработать регулярками, это самый надёжный способ. Например, так:

```js
const data1 = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('a.category__heading__name'),
  a => a.href.replace(/.+\/category\/(.+?)\/.+/, '$1')
);
console.log(data1);

const data2 = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('a.category__heading__name'),
  a => a.innerText
);
console.log(data2);

const data3 = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('span.category__heading__thin + span.category__heading__thin'),
  a => a.innerText.replace(/\((.+)P\)/, '$1')
);
console.log(data3);
```

```html
<a class="category__heading__name" href="/category/DVHrj/categ-name">Categ Name</a>
<span class="category__heading__thin">(201 items)</span>
<span class="category__heading__thin">(6P)</span>

<a class="category__heading__name" href="/category/DVHrj/categ-name">Categ Name</a>
<span class="category__heading__thin">(201 items)</span>
<span class="category__heading__thin">(6P)</span>

<a class="category__heading__name" href="/category/DVHrj/categ-name">Categ Name</a>
<span class="category__heading__thin">(201 items)</span>
<span class="category__heading__thin">(6P)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

На питоне вероятно проще без регулярок вообще, вот заготовка:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<a class="category__heading__name" href="/category/DVHrj/categ-name">Categ Name</a><span class="category__heading__thin">(201 items)</span><span class="category__heading__thin">(6P)</span>
<a class="category__heading__name" href="/category/DVHrj/categ-name">Categ Name</a><span class="category__heading__thin">(201 items)</span><span class="category__heading__thin">(6P)</span>
<a class="category__heading__name" href="/category/DVHrj/categ-name">Categ Name</a><span class="category__heading__thin">(201 items)</span><span class="category__heading__thin">(6P)</span>
'''

parser = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for child in parser.find_all():
    if child.name == 'a':
        print(child.text)
        s = child['href'].split('/')
        if len(s) > 3:
            print(s[2])
    elif child.name == 'span':   
        if child.text.endswith('P)') and len(child.text) > 3:
            print(child.text[1:-2])
```

Вывод:

```
Categ Name
DVHrj
6
Categ Name
DVHrj
6
Categ Name
DVHrj
6
```

Comment: Это не подходит. У меня JavaScript, который будет обрабатывать страниуц, которую спарсил